# Listing cells where checkboxes are checked

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Would anyone know a formula or way to see occupied cells in a column? I have an Excel checklist that's 500 rows long. All of my questions are in column A, then "Yes" and "No" checkboxes are columns B and C. I have SUM formulas for columns B and C and I can see that I have 490 "yes" and 10 "no". Instead of scrolling though 500 rows looking for those "no" answers I'd like to add a formula at the top of the sheet that shows the cells in column C that are occupied with a "no" answer (i.e. C49, C51, C255,...).

Comment: The answer will depend on which version of Excel you are using.

Comment: But the easy method is to use filter on the data tab and filter on the ones checked in Column C.

Comment: Checkboxes of which type? Form Controls or ActiveX controls?

Comment: How do your formulas look for calculating 490 and 10?

Comment: Excel v.2102. The majority of the sheet is protected and sorting won't.

Comment: Formula for sum is a basic =SUM(C1:C100) which gives me the total number of answers for each column. And, I'm just using a simple "1" as a "checkmark" in the corresponding column to keep my total tally.

Comment: try this: `=FILTER("C"&ROW(C:C),C:C=1)`

Comment: @Scott: close, thanks, but it's giving a #Value error. I'm trying some variations of that but no luck yet.

Comment: The values in C are `1` and `0` not `TRUE` and `FALSE`?

Comment: try `=FILTER("C"&ROW(C:C),C:C)`

Comment: My values are either 1 or an just an empty cell

Comment: Sorry, =FILTER("F"&ROW(F:F),F:F) returns a #VALUE!

Comment: You said the values are in C not F.

Comment: Yes, the values are in F, I was not exact when asking my original question for simplicity's sake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest the following formula:

```
=INDEX(ROW($C$2:$C$500), SMALL(IF(--($C$2:$C$500)=1, ROW($C$2:$C$500)-ROW($C$2)+1), ROW(1:1)))
```

<sup>This is an array formula which you would need to enter using **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**</sup>

It gives row numbers where your checked values might be located.

[image]

Comment: Good formula but it only returns the total sum (10) as a basic fx does. Thanks

Comment: It means you have the first checkbox checked  on row 10?

Comment: Drag the formula down for more results

Comment: Ah, lol! Hot digitty, that's the ticket! Thank you very much.

Comment: It could be, however, that Scott may come back with a nicer solution :)

Comment: Only if the OP has Office 365 with Filter, BTW My formula in Office 365 works as I typed it above.

Comment: Yes, I'm running 365. I did modify Scotts formula to the column that I wanted exactly =FILTER("F"&ROW(F:F),F:F=1) but I get a #SPILL! error when I do. My sheet is active from row F7:F355 and nearly everything else is protected.

Comment: If you get `#SPILL` it means the number of rows will cause the results to overwrite cells that have data in them.  You can wrap in TEXTJOIN: `=TEXTJOIN(", ",,FILTER("F"&ROW(F:F),F:F=1))` @Nepeta2099

Comment: @ZygD BTW the INDEX is not needed:  `=SMALL(IF(--($C$2:$C$500)=1, ROW($C$2:$C$500), ROW(1:1))`

Comment: Awesome! Thanks Scott, that works even better. I can see all of my desired cells now that relate to that column. I work as an auditor and the inspection sheets are ~170 pages long, and I'd normally have to slowly scroll through each page looking for something that was marked in the "no" column but now I can see exactly where I need to go to address the problem. I've saved your formula and will use it often. Thanks, again.

Answer (score 0):

You might find "Autofilter" as useful as the other answers.

To create an autofilter, in Excel (LibreOffice 4 has it in a menu):
Simply select all your data, include the header row, then hold <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> and hit <kbd>L</kbd> while doing so.

You will see a small downward pointing triangle for each of your columns.
Clicking on that triangle will reveal a menu, where you can select to view certain types of rows;
e.g. "yes" or "no" -rows for a column, useful even with those words collected in the same column.

No extra formulas required.

Use the same key combination to remove (disable) the autofilter.

Comment: That does work well on an open sheet but I can't use on the protected version that I'm working on now. Noted for later though, Thanks.